# bootstrap drop down menu won't drop down

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

this is my navigation panel in haml with bootstrap. This is something that was left behind by another developer. My html/css/design skill is very little.

```
.navbar.navbar-static-top
  .navbar-inner
    .container
      %a.btn.btn-navbar(data-target=".nav-collapse" data-toggle="collapse")
        %span.icon-bar
      %a.brand{ href: 'http://www.url.com' }
        =image_tag 'amazons3url'
      .nav-collapse.collapse
        %ul.nav.pull-left
          %li.divider-vertical
          -if student_signed_in?
            %li.dropdown
              %a.dropdown-toggle(data-toggle='dropdown' href='#')
                =t('.account')
                %b.caret
              %ul.dropdown
                %li
                  =link_to(t('.register_event'), new_event_path)
                %li
                  =link_to(t('.events'), events_path)
                %li
                  =link_to(t('.sign_out'), destroy_student_session_path,
                           method: :delete)
          -else
            %li 
              =link_to(t('navigationbar.sponsors'), brands_path) 
            %li 
              =link_to(t('navigationbar.works'), page_path('how_it_works'))
            %li
              =link_to(t('navigationbar.about'), page_path('about'))
            %li
              =link_to(t('navigationbar.signup'),
                new_student_registration_path)
            %li.divider-vertical
            %li.divider-vertical
            %li
              =link_to(t('navigationbar.login'), new_student_session_path)
            %li.divider-vertical
              =link_to(t('navigationbar.event'), new_sponsorship_path)

          %li.divider-vertical
          %li.divider-vertical
          %li.dropdown
            %a.dropdown-toggle(data-toggle='dropdown' href='#')
              =t('navigationbar.language')
            %ul.dropdown-menu
              %li
                =link_to('繁體中文', locale: 'zh-HK')
              %li
                =link_to('简体中文', locale: 'zh-CN')
              %li
                =link_to('English', locale: 'en')
```

I am having trouble with this part

```
      %li.dropdown
        %a.dropdown-toggle(data-toggle='dropdown' href='#')
          =t('navigationbar.language')
        %ul.dropdown-menu
          %li
            =link_to('繁體中文', locale: 'zh-HK')
          %li
            =link_to('简体中文', locale: 'zh-CN')
          %li
            =link_to('English', locale: 'en')
```

when I click on the language it will go to this

```
# instead of the links
```

it semi work if I change

```
%ul.dropdown-menu
```

to

```
%ul
```

the links will be bullet points and its really ugly. I have checked the bootstrap doc, I should be specifying the class of ul to dropdown-menu so I don't see what is the problem?

this dropdown isn't working for me either

```
 -if student_signed_in?
            %li.dropdown
              %a.dropdown-toggle(data-toggle='dropdown' href='#')
                =t('.account')
                %b.caret
              %ul.dropdown
                %li
                  =link_to(t('.register_event'), new_event_path)
                %li
                  =link_to(t('.events'), events_path)
                %li
                  =link_to(t('.sign_out'), destroy_student_session_path,
                           method: :delete)
```

Answer (score 0):

check if you've included the js plugin that is needed in order to show the dropdown menu, if not when you click on it is only going to add the # at the end of the url.

check this http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#dropdowns